# GUI Designer in Netbeans [Qt or GTK]

Tags: java, swing, qt, user-interface, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans recently for developing Java applications especially Swing components and Design tab has been a boon.

I felt Swing component [jTable] was insufficient to my needs and so I thought of writing the application from scratch using GTK framework.

I installed the library like:

```
sudo apt-get install libjava-gnome-java
```

and everything is working fine. But I DO NOT FIND THE DESIGN tab anymore. It is just a console application which is invoking a window! Can we not change that? Is the Design tab available to only Swing framework? I have checked it with GTK so don't know much about Qt.

I was told Eclipse has a plugin for Qt [don't know...google search hinted me] but I would like to stick with Netbeans.

Is there anyway to 'ivoke' the Design tab for developing GTK or Qt appliations?

Comment: So.. you're writing this app. exclusively for *nix?  Why was `JTable` insufficient to the application requirement?

Comment: Yes, the application is meant to run only on *nix. jTable cannot add rows randomly if the data exceeds the rows available like for ex: consider I have 4 columns and 3 rows [default] and the data is actually a String[] of 16 items, then, jTable will throw an exception on inserting the 13 element but not increasing the no. of rows to accommodate the given data

Comment: *".. jTable will throw an exception on inserting the 13 element"*  ..not if you do it right!

Comment: @AndrewThompson will you please elaborate the "not if you do it right" part ?

I am kind of a rookie-programmer in Java

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of doing it wrong, and I'll try to have a close look at it.  But that is something that is worthy of it's own question.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the Design tab available to only Swing framework?

The documentation for NetBeans says this:

> "In the IDE you can create JFC/Swing or AWT (Abstract Window Toolkit) forms, pre-built sample application skeletons, or any class that is based on the JavaBeans component architecture using the provided templates."

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/run_java_guis.htm

Apparently, the relevant templates are available for Qt.  [This page](https://netbeans.org/kb/72/cnd/qt-applications.html) from the documentation includes a simple example of using the "Qt Designer" to create a form in NetBeans